Как сделать полноценный аналог DATABASE MAIl (MSSQL) в PostgreSQL?
в MS SQL есть модуль DATABASE MAIL
которому можно прямо в коде процедуры отдать письмо для отправки по электронной почты,
даже с вложениями
например, письмо об успешной регистрации в какой-то системе
где-то в базе лежит шаблон, который наполняется знаниями и отправляется с помощью этого модуля на адрес зарегистрировавшегося пользователя
Читал про sendmail - особо ничего такого нет.

pgsql так не может. Можно создать таблицу с письмами и кроном запускать скрипт который с БД брать будет письма и заниматься отправкой

Посмотрите здесь: https://habr.com/ru/articles/650059/
